# How to set alarm in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, background-service

I am working on an alarm app. I want to know that how can I set the alarm in flutter app as in the android we use alarm manager to trigger alarm function. Need for both platform Ios and Android.

Answer (score 5):

Follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3671 for updates.

So, for now, you can use regular Java and Objective-C code to solve the problem.

Comment: This seems to be tracked at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32164 now.